# Is there a way to use variables from another Python file in your main file?

Tags: python, list, file, variables

I am working on a project where I have to write multiple lists, with no way to go around it. I am trying to figure out a way to have another Python file with all these lists so that the main file, which contains the important code, is clean without excessive lines of lists; i.e. `main.py` uses lists from `lists.py` for the program. Is this possible? If not, is there any other way to go about this situation? Thanks.

Comment: `import` is not restricted to built-in modules.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the python's module import

> File 1 in 'parent_folder/data.py':

```
list_1=[1,2,3]
list_2=[4,5,6]
```

> File 2 in 'parent_folder/main.py':

```
from data import list_1,list_2

#access items
print('list 1:',list_1)
print('list 2:', list_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this for example:

```
from yourpythonfile import *
```

This import everythings. But is better not to do star imports you can also specify the specific variables

Comment: Don't star import. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/4046632

Comment: Agree with buran better to specify what you want to import

Comment: @buran While that is generally good advice, OP's use-case seems to be one in which it is the desired behavior. They have a module of their own creation and are asking how to bring everything defined there into their main program. Although, even there, it couldn't hurt to be more explicit.

Comment: @JohnColeman, OP wanst to use the variable e.g. `eggs` from the other file `spam.py`. so, what is the problem to do `import spam`, then reference `spam.eggs` when they want to use `eggs`?  In this case no start import and is clear what comes from where. I understand they may not want to import each variable individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can
Either

```
from list import *
print(list_26)
```

Or

```
import list
print(list.list_26)
```

Or

```
import list as l
print(l.list_26)
```

First one is the most easiest way and I recommend using `from filename import *`